# How to set background color on stacks in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, view, vstack

I'm trying to utilize the light & dark mode in SwiftUI, but I am struggling to get an elevated color that fits for both light and dark mode. Such as the SystemGray(0-6) colors that Apple showcased.

I have attempted to use `.background(Color.primary/secondary)` on my `VStack` or `HStack` and it doesn't seem to get a nice color. It's either black or dark gray. There doesn't seam to be the tertiary or quaternary colors that Apple talked about. How would I get the color of the app to match the health app? Light grey screen background with white backgrounds for the buttons in light mode and then in dark mode have a black background and dark gray buttons?

Currently, in my code below, I am using a blue background just for testing as primary/secondary does not work. Has anyone found a way to get this working properly?

```
VStack {
    Text("8:20").fontWeight(.semibold).font(.system(size: 80)).foregroundColor(.primary)
    Text("Hours worked").font(.body).foregroundColor(.secondary)
}
.padding()
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(15)
.shadow(radius: 10)
```

Comment: primary and secondary are really foreground colors. Have you tried using colorInvert on primary or secondary for your background?

Comment: UIColor defines a number of system colours e.g. systemBackground and there is a Color initialiser using UIColor so that you can get the colours you want indirectly.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like SwiftUI `Color` class has a limited amount of colours, it seems incomplete. I needed the default background colour so I could add some transparency.

The `UIColor` class has `systemBackground` which was exactly what I needed. I was able to solve my problem using this:

`VStack(){ /** Code here **/}.background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground).opacity(0.95))`

You might find more colours that fit what you want in UIColor.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/

Comment: Great idea. Weird that SwiftUI doesn't have an accessor for this directly, but using UIColor as the basis is a smart workaround.

Answer (score 8):

I may be misunderstanding your issue, but are you asking about *determining* if the device is in light or dark mode? (Your sample code works the same in both modes)? If so, have you tried using the `Environment` variable `colorScheme`?

```
@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
```

And an example on usage for theming:

```
extension Color {
    static let blue = Color.blue
    static let yellow = Color.yellow

    static func backgroundColor(for colorScheme: ColorScheme) -> Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            return yellow
        } else {
            return blue
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
    var body: some View {
        VStack
        {
            Text("8:20").fontWeight(.semibold).font(.system(size: 80)).foregroundColor(.primary)
            Text("Hours worked").font(.body).foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.backgroundColor(for: colorScheme))
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .shadow(radius: 10)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for this case is to derive system color from UIColor.

```
Color(uiColor: UIColor.systemGray6)
```

If you need custom theme dependent color you can configure a custom color set in Assets.xcassets. There you can define one color for light mode and a different color for dark mode. Then just use this color set name throughout your app as you would with any other color name.

In Assets.xcassets, click the + at the bottom and then "New Color Set".
Give your color a name.
In "Appearances" within the attributes inspector, select "Any, Dark"
You can then set a different color for each and then use it's name as your color in your app.